# Log D365 script errors on Application Insights

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-application-insights, telemetry, dynamics-365

I'm trying to use Application Insights to automatically log form/script errors from my Dynamics 365 instance but they're not being tracked.

I started by creating an Application Insights resource in Azure and adding the following JavaScript (extracted from the Getting Started section from the App Insights Resource) to my CRM form (just like this [walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sample-mscrm)):

```
var appInsights=window.appInsights||function(config){
function i(config) { t[config] = function () { var i = arguments; t.queue.push(function () { t[config].apply(t, i) }) } }var t={config:config},u=document,e=window,o="script",s="AuthenticatedUserContext",h="start",c="stop",l="Track",a=l+"Event",v=l+"Page",y=u.createElement(o),r,f;y.src=config.url||"https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js";u.getElementsByTagName(o)[0].parentNode.appendChild(y);try{t.cookie = u.cookie}catch(p){}for(t.queue=[],t.version="1.0",r=["Event","Exception","Metric","PageView","Trace","Dependency"];r.length;)i("track"+r.pop());return i("set"+s),i("clear"+s),i(h+a),i(c+a),i(h+v),i(c+v),i("flush"),config.disableExceptionTracking||(r="onerror",i("_"+r),f=e[r],e[r]=function(config,i,u,e,o){var s=f&&f(config,i,u,e,o);return s!==!0&&t["_"+r](config,i,u,e,o),s}),t
    }({
            instrumentationKey:"XXXXX"
    });

    window.appInsights=appInsights;
    appInsights.trackPageView();
```

After this, I started to see data related to page views and page load times so the tracking is enabled:

[image]

My next action was then to force some script errors in the form to visualize then in Azure. In order to do this, I added a JavaScript function in the OnChange event of a field to get an "undefined" error:

[image]

As you can see in the previous image, the error is being thrown in D365 as expected but there's no record of it in Application Insights. After some tests I started to suspect that CRM is catching that error and not letting it to reach the browser (the error doesn't appear in the console). To confirm my suspicions, I created a HTML web page with the same App Insights configuration and I simulated the error to see if in that scenario the errors are being tracked and the answer is yes:

[image]

So it seems that Dynamics is "swallowing" the error and preventing it to be logged. Have anyone faced this issue before? Is there a workaround that I can use to successfully track the errors into App Insights?

Thanks!

Comment: Very Happy to see my walkthrough is helping the community.. did you try try {    ... } catch (ex) {    appInsights.trackException(ex); }

Answer (score 1):

Dynamics CRM will handle custom script block in a special way.

We have to catch the exception gracefully in our form js & log it in AppInsights like below.

```
try
{
   ...
}
catch (ex)
{
   appInsights.trackException(ex);
}
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#trackexception)

Comment: Thanks Arun, I was aware of the trackException function but I'd like to avoid this approach mainly because the CRM instance has more than 200 JavaScript web resources and refactor all of them to include this is going to be painful. One of the main reasons to use App Insights to log script errors was that it will avoid to refactor A LOT of code (it should work only adding a web resource to the form), but unfortunately it has proved to be tricky in a CRM context...